# EF6 always FK exception after delete a row that cause FK exception

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using WPF and EF6 in my project.

I have 2 tables city(id_city, city_name) and person(id_person, name, id_city), id_city in person table is a FK.

Example I have 2 city C1 and C2 and 1 person P1 live in city C1.
Then I try to delete C1 with this code

```
//I selected city C1 row in datagrid
city o = (city)cityDataGrid.SelectedCells[0].Item;
try
{
    context.city.Remove(o);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

It raised a FK exception obviously. Then I try to delete C2 like this and it raised a FK exception although C2 didn't have any person.
So what should i do to fix this?

Comment: What's the full text of the exception? The obvious reason is that there's another table referring to `City`.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: Does this exception occur with *exactly* the code you show? This exception usually occurs when an object is removed from an entity's collection property (something like `city.Persons.Remove(person)`).

Comment: Case 1:

`city.Remove(c2)` //c2 don't have any person

`db.SaveChanges()` //c2 deleted

`city.Remove(c1)` //c1 have 1 person

`db.SaveChanges()` //exception

| Case 2:

`city.Remove(c1)` //c1 have 1 person

`db.SaveChanges()` //exception

`city.Remove(c2)` //c2 don't have any person

`db.SaveChanges()` //exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asked a question about `DbContext` `.Add()`, I learned that I should change my code like this:

```
//I selected city C1 row in datagrid
city o = (city)cityDataGrid.SelectedCells[0].Item;
using (var context = new myDbContext())
{
    try
    {
        context.city.Remove(o);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The explanation is in this question [Entity Framework Insert bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593533/entity-framework-insert-bug)

Answer (score 0):

Using the default settings, this will always cause an exception - the id_city field of a person record must point to a valid record in the city table.

To change this

1. Change the person.id_city field to allow null values
2. Change the foreign key definition to "on delete set null"

This assumes that you don't want to delete a person record just because you delete their city.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: But I don't understand why C2 cause an exception, C2 don't have any person reference to it. I try to delete C2 before C1 then C2 deleted and C1 caused an exception.

Comment: Sql server doesn't throw these errors for no reason ... are you sure you don't have any person records referencing that city? Please show some minimal code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this issue.

Comment: I added a link to an example project that have this issue