# Entity Framework Insert bug?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I used EF 6.2.0 DB first, SQL Server 2017

I created a table to test this

```
create table Person
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(50)
)
```

And I created a form to insert, this is button click event:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.id = Convert.ToInt32(txbID.Text);
    p.name = txbName.Text;

    try
    {
        db.People.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("###Ex:" + ex.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

First, I insert a person with `ID = 1`.

Then, I insert another person with `ID = 1` and it caused this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Person__3213E83F397C4503'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Person'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Finally, I insert a person with `ID = 2` and it still show the same exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Person__3213E83F397C4503'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Person'. The duplicate key value is (1).

After the first exception, insert any ID will cause the same exception `The duplicate key value is (1)`. I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a bug - I suspect you haven't really understood how the `DbContext` works.

When you try to insert the second person with `ID = 1` which will obviously create the error, that object (that causes this error) is now part of the `DbContext` (of the `db.People` collection).

If you add another person, with `ID = 2`, your "problematic" second person with `ID=1` is **still** part of the `DbContext` (`db.Person`) - **unless** you've specifically cleaned up (removed that troublesome person, or created a new `DbContext` altogether).

So after adding the person with `ID = 2`, your `DbContext` now has a Person with ID=1 and another one with ID=2 to be saved when calling `.SaveChanges()` - and that will **OF COURSE** again fail with the same error - it's the same problem as before......

One way to solve this would be to *explicitly* create the `DbContext` inside your `btnSubmit_Click` method:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new YourDbContextType())
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.id = Convert.ToInt32(txbID.Text);
        p.name = txbName.Text;

        try
        {
             db.People.Add(p);
             db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("###Ex:" + ex.ToString());
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a same problem when I `.Remove()` but I understood now. Thanks for your explanation.